# How to download a file from a server, and and post it again in another one (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, axios, node-streams

In my node application, I want to get a file from one server, and then upload it into another server. I have the following code:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const FormData = require("form-data");
const { createWriteStream, createReadStream } = require("fs");

const response = await axios({
  url: "https://first-server/image.png",
  method: "GET",
  responseType: "stream",
});

await new Promise((res) => {
  response.data.pipe(
    createWriteStream("someFile.png").on("finish", () => {
      res();
    })
  );
});

const form = new FormData();
form.append("file", createReadStream("./someFile.png"));

const postHeaders = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + env("APY_KEY"),
    ...form.getHeaders(),
  },
  data: form,
};

axios.post("https://second-server.com/api", form, postHeaders)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  })
```

This code works, but I think it's not the right way to do this, since it writes the retrieved file into the local disc before posting it again into the second server. I need to be able to upload the file without writing it into the local disc. Is there any way?

Comment: Does your second server require the data all at once, or can it be piped as it comes in? If it requires the data in its entirety, it is inevitable that it has to be buffered on disk before sending off to the second server.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-stream-pipe/ just try reading the documentation. There is even an example in there which does almost exactly what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `form.append("file", createReadStream("./someFile.png"));` with
`form.append("file", response.data);`

Both `response.data` and `createReadStream("./someFile.png")` are readable stream.

Comment: This is strange. That was my first attempt, and didn't work. But now I've tried it again and it's working

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** You can directly transfer returned stream data without any need to create temporary file.

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const FormData = require("form-data");

axios({
  url: "http://localhost:3000/temp.png",
  method: "GET",
  responseType: "stream",
}).then(response => {

    response.data.on("data", function(data) {
        const form = new FormData();
        form.append("file", data);

        const postHeaders = {
          headers: {
            // Authorization: "Bearer " + env("APY_KEY"),
            ...form.getHeaders(),
          },
          data: form,
        };

        axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api", form, postHeaders)
        .then((response) => {
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error)
        });
    });

})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: .on "data" runs multiple time, i think it is giving chunk of data, still helpless